# What good is Unity DI in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I'm slightly new to Unity and IoC, but not to MVC. I've been reading and reading about using Unity with MVC and the only really useful thing I'm consistently seeing is the ability to get free DI with the controllers.

To go from this:

```
    public HomeController() : this(new UserRepository())
    {
    }

    public HomeController(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.UserRepository = userRepository;
    }
```

To this:

```
    public HomeController(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.UserRepository = userRepository;
    }
```

Basically, allowing me to drop the no parameter constructor. This is great and all and I'm going to implement this for sure, but it doesn't seem like it's anything really that great for all the hype about IoC libraries. Going the way of using Unity as a service locator sounds compelling, but many would argue it's an anti pattern.

So my question is, with service locating out of the question and some DI opportunities with Views and Filters, is there anything else I gain from using Unity? I just want to make sure I'm not missing something wonderful like free DI support for all class constructors.

EDIT:

I understand the testability purpose behind using Unity DI with MVC controllers. But all I would have to do is add that one extra little constructor, nix Unity, and I could UnitTest just the same. Where is the great benefit in registering your repository types and having a custom controller factory when the alternative is simpler? The alternative being native DI. I guess I'm really wondering what is so great about Unity (or any IoC library) besides Service Locating which is bad. Is free Controller DI really the ONLY thing I get from Unity?

Answer (score 1):

A good IoC container not only creates the concrete class for you, it examines the couplings between that type and other types. If there are additional dependencies, it resolves them and creates instances of all of the classes that are required.

You can do fancy things like conditional binding. Here's an example using Ninject (my preferred IoC):

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IValueCalculator>().To<LinqValueCalculator>();

ninjectKernel.Bind<IValueCalculator>().To<IterativeValueCalculator().WhenInjectedInto<LimitShoppingCart>();
```

What ninject is doing here is creating an instance of IterativeValueCalculator when injecting into LimitShoppingCart and an instance of LinqValueCalulator for any other injection.

Greatest benefit is separation of concern (decoupling) and testability.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding why Service Locator is considered bad(by some guys) you can read [this blog-post by Mark Seeman](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Answering on your question `What is so good in Unity` I can say that apart from all the testability, loosely-coupling and other blah-blah-blah-s everyone is talking about you can use such awesome feature like **[Unity's Interception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660891%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)** which allows to do some [AOP-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) things. I've used it in some of last projects and liked it pretty much. Strongly recommended!

p.s. Seems like `Castle Windsor` DI container has similar feature as well(called Interceptors). Other containers - not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Besides testing (which is a huge benefit and should not be under estimated), dependency injection allows:

**Maintainability**: The ability to alter the behavior of your code with a single change.

If you decide to change the class that retrieves your users across all your controllers/services etc. without dependency injection, you need to update each and every constructor plus any other random new instances that are being created, provided you remember where each one lives.  DI allows you to change one definition that is then used across all implementations.

[Scope](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes): With a single line of code you can alter your implementation to create a singleton, a class that is only created on each new web request or on each new thread

**Readability**: The use of dependency injection means that all your concrete classes are defined in one place.  As a developer coming onto a project, I can quickly and easily see exactly which concrete classes are mapped to which interfaces and know that there are no hidden implemetations.  It means I can not only read the code better but empowers me to have the confidence to develop against the code

**Design**: I believe using dependency injection helps create well designed code.  You automatically code to interfaces, your code becomes cleaner because you haven't got strange blocks of code to help you test

And let's no forget...

**Testing**:  Testing is huge!  Dependency injection allows you to test your code without having to write code specifically for tests.  Ok, you can create a new constructor, but what is stop anyone else using that constructor for a purpose it has not been intended for.  What if another developer comes along six months later and adds production logic to your 'test' constructor. Ok, so you can make it `internal` but this can still be used by production code.  Why give them the option.

My experience with IoC frameworks has been largely around [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/).  As such, the above is based on what I know of Ninject, however the same principles should remain the same across other frameworks.

Comment: Do you recommended any good open source projects that implement Unity DI?  I would like to see another programmers structure and compare it to mine in order to possibly improve my solution.

Answer (score 0):

No the main point is that you then have a mapping somewhere that specifies the concrete type of IUserRepository. And the reason that you might like that is that you can then create a UnitTest that specifies a mocked version of IUserRepository and execute your tests without changing anything in your controller.

Comment: But @Tim, all I would have to do is add that one extra little constructor, nix Unity, and I could UnitTest just the same. Where is the great benefit in registering your repository types and having a custom controller factory when the alternative is simpler?

Answer (score 0):

Testability mostly, but id suggest looking at Ninject, it plays well with MVC.  To get the full benefits of IOC you should really be combining this with Moq or a similar mocking framework.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the testability, I think you can also add the extensibility as one of the advantages. One of the best practices of Software Development is "working with abstractions, not with implementations" and, while you can do it in several ways, Unity provides a very extensible and easy way to achieve this. By using this, you will be creating abstractions that will define the contracts that your component must comply. Say that you want to change totally the Repository that your application currently uses. With DI you just "swap" the component without the need of changing a single line of code on your application. If you are using hard references, you might need to change and recompile your application because of a component that is external to it (In a different layer)

So, bottom line, IMHO, using DI helps you to have pluggable components in your application and have a [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) application design